# Which is faster? Set comparison or Counter comparison? why

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two strings:

```
a = "hello world"
b = "world hello"
```

which would run faster?

```py
set(a)==set(b)
```

or

```py
from collections import Counter

Counter(a)==Counter(b)
```

Why? and is there anything that runs faster?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it? And why are you asking?

Comment: These are two very different operations. One thinks `Helllo` is the same string as `Helo`. Worry about semantic differences before you worry about speed.

Comment: I found set comparison to be faster but I want to know why and any other alternative to these. Basically I am trying to find if two sentences contain the same set of words with the fastest approach

Comment: "Why"? Why *wouldn't* it be? The counter has more information in it that needs to be compared (values, not just keys).

Comment: That said, this kind of question often has implementation-defined answers -- thus, ones that can change without notice between runtime versions. They don't last, for that reason, making it hard to classify them as "practical", within the meaning given in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic; and an answer that isn't guaranteed by the language specification is also innately hard to make canonical, as our site goals call for.

Comment: A note: On Python 2, the answer is *clearly* `set`, because all `Counter` specific features are implemented in pure Python on Python 2. The comparison is inherited from `dict`, and runs fast, but building the `Counter`s is a slow Python level loop. In Python 3, the runtimes will be much closer, as they added an element counting accelerator to `Counter` a while back, and constructing the `Counter` will be much cheaper. `set` will usually still win, but it won't be by nearly as much as on Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` comparison would run faster. There are two main reasons for this:

1) There is more information in `Counter()` compared to `set()`

2) There are more operations required to build up a `Counter()` object compare to a `set()`.

Roughly speaking, `Counter()` is a dictionary, which consist of key value pairs. In Counter the values have the special meaning of counting the number of occurrences of the key.
By contrast, `set()` only contains information about the keys.

---

## EDIT

When it comes to addressing the question of which one should you use, this depends on what are you trying to achieve, given that the two expressions are not equivalent:

```
from collections import Counter

a = "hello world"
b = "world helo"

set(a) == set(b)
# True

Counter(a) == Counter(b)
# False
```

Therefore it is hard to give more hints in this direction.

Comment: Okay, now this clarified everything. Great explanation

Comment: Appreciate it norok2.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to benchmark simple expressions like these, you can use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module. Or better yet, if you have IPython installed, you can simply use the [timeit](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) magic command, for example:

`%timeit Counter(a)==Counter(b)`

Comment: i did time it, I want to know why set comparison is faster than counter comparison. and if there is any alternative to these two

Comment: @Kai, ...if that's what you want to know, why isn't that the question you asked? And they aren't even alternatives *to each other*, since they do two different things, and will often have different results when operating on the same data.

Comment: 1. You are mixing set and counter creation with comparison in the two examples, please make it clear what performance you are trying to benchmark, creation, comparsion or both? 2. In theory, both of these can be implemented with a hash table, but the counter have to do some extra counting.

Comment: Here's how you should design the benchmarks to learn more about these two data structures:
1. %timeit set(a)
2. %timeit Counter(a)
3. x = set(a); y = set(b)； %timeit x == y
4. x = Counter(a); y = Counter(b); %timeit x == y

Comment: I don't know if its specific to the type of data I use. I just tried it on strings. well they are comparing whether the two set of strings contain the same set of words or not. Thought it was obvious.

Comment: @satoru Thank you for disecting it for me. Can you be specifically tell me how the speed varies in each case? like which is faster in creation and which is faster in comparison ?

Comment: @satoru: Got it!

Comment: @Kai Please make your own assumptions with whatever knowledge you have about these data structures and then use benchmarks to check if they are correct.

Comment: Wrong assumptions can lead to poor coding practices. I got everything I need now. Thank you for helping out!